# Getting an character as a password with "*" sign and match with your password

Tags: c, passwords

Hello I want to create a program that asks me for a two digit password. I have created the password and the password should match. If the first digit entered is wrong then immidiatly asks one more time , if the first digit is right then is one more left. It should runs just 5 times. If none of this 5 times is right it ends and when I type the password should be as star sign "*".

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char password=0x00;
    int a=0;
   int b;
    char password2=0x00;
    int c,e;
    do{
        printf("\nEnter a character");

        password=getche();

       if(password=='1'){

        b=(passowrd-48)*10;

        password2=getche();

       if(password=='2'){

       c=password2-48;  

      e= c+b;
       }
}        
        a++;
    }while(e !=12 && a<10); 

        return 0;
    }
```

Maybe any hint?

Comment: What's the code below for?

Comment: You should use `getch()` for not echoing what was typed, and then `putchar("*");`.

Comment: I am trying to program the described program. But i  know it is wrong

Comment: So we should try to get that piece of code right?

Comment: If so, tell us in the question.

Comment: I dont really know if it is right or not. I just should implement a program that gets two characters(but in real i type two numbers) that should match with my password eg. "99"  and the typed password should be with star sign and if 5 times is wrong the can not enter anymore

Comment: Added below. You should indent well and remove duplicate blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is get the char (password) but not echoing it, and put a "*" there as a place holder. First is done by `getch()`, which will not echo. Second is by having a `putchar("*")` following the input.

---

Here's the possible implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    char password; 
    int a = 0;
    // int a=0, b=0, c, e; 
    do { 
        printf("\nEnter a character");
        password=getch();
        putchar("*");
        if(password!='1') { printf("\n\n"); continue; }
        password=getch();
        putchar("*");
        if(password!='2') { printf("\n\n"); continue; }
        // The password is correct, do something here
        a++; 
    } while(a<10); 
    return 0; 
}
```

---

Also fixed the indents and blank lines in chaos and removed useless variables. `password` isn't used elsewhere except as a "buffer" for input, so it's OK to override it. You have already compared digit by digit of the password, no need to calculate what it is in decimal and then compare it.

Comment: Here is a small problem,  even if i type the password more then 10 times it still works. Because with continue it goes back and does not check if a<10.What do you think?

Comment: I arranged it, Thank you

Comment: @MrASD Sorry if I didn't reply rapidly. Is that still a problem now?

Comment: @LuisColorado thats the C++ way. He included iostream first, right?

Comment: @JohnsonSteward, yes, but the question was not tagged C++, just C.  I know what is <cstdio>, but we are (all) messing C and C++ in this question.  And its supposed that answerers know language tricks better than requestors.

Answer (score 1):

This program should work on Windows but you should know that `getch` isn't a `C` standard library, nor is it defined by `POSIX`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h>


int main (void) {
    char password[20];
    int c,i=0;
    char ch = '*';
    while ((c = getch()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        password[i] = (char)c;
        i++;
        putchar(ch);
    }

    printf("\nYour Password is %s\n",password);
    return 0;
}
```

Any way you could write the function `getch` yourself like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int getch(void);

int main (void) {
    char password[50];
    int c,i=0;
    char ch = '*';
    while ((c = getch()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        password[i] = (char)c;
        i++;
        putchar(ch);
    }

    printf("\nYour Password is %s\n",password);
    return 0;
}

int getch (void){
    int ch;
    struct termios oldt, newt;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag = newt.c_lflag & ~(ICANON|ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);

    return ch;
}
```

Output:

```
michi@michi-laptop:~$ ./program 
******
Your Password is passwd
```

The `getch` function needs some fix, but at least you get an Idea.